# How to build a bar chart with stepline chart using highcharts

Tags: highcharts

[image: combined line chart and bar chart using jquery highcharts]

I want to create a chart  for 'allocated space' and 'usage space' which may vary from time to time. I can`t  create this combined chart. If any one help me out it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: How it should look like ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sebastian. I want a graph just like I have mentioned in the image.

Comment: There are column chart, but not pie chart with step ? It is a little bit unclear.

Comment: I have edited my question. I think now it will be helpful !!

Comment: Where there is pie chart? Pie chart looks like [this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic). In your case its column and line chart with defined step. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/yp6tL6w2/

Comment: Thanks  a lot Sebastian. Your jsfiddle example was great.

Comment: Ok so mark ma answer as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case its column and line chart with defined `step`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/yp6tL6w2